# Using jQuery to remove initial text from a textarea

Tags: jquery, symfony, textarea

I have a textarea built through Symfony with the following code:

Controller:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
    ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name:'))
    ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'Email Address:'))
    ->add('subject', 'text', array('label' => 'Subject:'))
    ->add('message', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Message:'))
    ->getForm();
```

Template:

```
<div>
    {{ form_errors(form.message) }}
    <p class="label">{{ form_label(form.message) }}</p>
    {{ form_widget(form.message, { 'attr' : { 'class' : 'input', 'id' : 'message', 'rows' : '8' } }) }}
</div>
```

Which results in the following HTML:

```
<div>   
    <p class="label"><label for="form_message" class="required">Message:</label></p>
    <textarea id="form_message" name="form[message]" required="required"    class="input" id="message" rows="8">Type your message here</textarea>
</div>
```

Now, when the text area is focused on, I want that initial text to disappear.  I'm just not sure how to do it.  I've tried:

```
$("#message").focus(function() {
    if (this.text() == "Type your message here") {
        this.text("");
    }
});
```

But to no avail.

Comment: use .val() not .text() for textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple problems with your code.

At first, for textarea you don't use `.text()`, use `.val()` instead as for many other form objects.
Refer to the object inside the focus functions like `$(this)` instead of only `this`.
And lastly, your textarea has 2 id's `#message` and `#form_message`, use only 1 ID so the HTML results as:

```
<div>   
  <p class="label"><label for="form_message" class="required">Message:</label></p>
  <textarea name="form[message]" required="required" class="input" id="message" rows="8">Type your message here</textarea>
</div>
```

And the corrected jQuery function results as:

```
$("#message").focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Type your message here") {
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, and good call on the second id.  Didn't notice that Symfony auto-generated one for me.

Comment: why not just use a placeHolder?

Comment: @praveen yeah placeholder would probably be easier, but at least this way it'll have backwards compatibility for older browsers.

Comment: Yeah, I actually just found a placeholder tutorial which seems to do the trick, with the exception of highlighting the textarea as having an error on focus.  But, aside from that, it works.  Just not sure if the error highlighting is due to HTML5 or something Symfony is doing with its validation.

Comment: Link to the placeholder code in question: http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html